# invoke-command doesn't work as expected

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I'm trying to use invoke-command to find a specific process using this code

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $selected_server.ServerName -ArgumentList $selected_server.ProcessId -ScriptBlock {Get-Process -Name "winlogon" | where{$_.Id -like $args[0]} }
```

This command doesn't work, but if I use the numeric value contained in 
`$selected_server.ProcessId` that is 8900, instead of using `$args[0]`, it works.

I also tried to execute this command to verify if variables are read correctly and it seems so

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $selected_server.ServerName -ArgumentList $selected_server.ProcessId -ScriptBlock {$args[0]; $args[0].gettype().fullname}

> 8900
> System.Int32
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know why but this works ( maybe `$args` in `foreach-object scriptblock` is `out of scope`):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $selected_server.ServerName `
-ArgumentList $selected_server.ProcessId -ScriptBlock `
{param ($x) Get-Process -Name "winlogon" | where{$_.Id -like $x} }
```

Answer (score 2):

C.B's answer is good & works anywhere you have remoting available (v2.0 & higher), but there is another (easier) way if you're using PowerShell 3.0 - the `Using` scope modifier. See [`about_Remote_Variables`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj149005.aspx)

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $selected_server.ServerName -ArgumentList $selected_server.ProcessId -ScriptBlock {Get-Process -Name "winlogon" | where{$_.Id -like  $Using:selected_server.ProcessId} }
```